# Can not resolve AppCompactActivity

Tags: java, android, appcompatactivity

I know this question has been asked a number of times and trying all those solutions I am still not finding a way out.
Android Studio shows error - 'can't resolve symbol AppCompactActivity'.

I tried: clean project, clean Gradle cache, file-> invalidate cache/restart, but it still shows the error.

[image: My import files]

(AppCompactActivity is shown as unused import) and these are my dependencies

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: Looks like it is resolved and you aren't using it if it is gray

Answer (score -1):

using the old-reliable File->Invalidate Caches/Restart can dp the trick. Always try this when you feel something is magically wrong with Android Studio